# How do I make my chrome extension open up to the window user last exited

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

Hey I made a note taking chrome extension and wanted to add a feature such that when the user re-opens the extension it goes to the last popup they were previously on. For example if the user was last on Note 3 and they exited out of that page, when they open the extension again it will go to Note 3.

Here is the link to all my code I have as well as a screenshot of what it looks like: https://github.com/SanthoshVelaga/NoteTakingApp/tree/master/NoteTakingApp

I have tried experimenting with the manifest.json under the "default_popup" which I believe could be part of the solution. Right now it is set by default to open to Note 1.

Here is the pseudocode which is how I was thinking about solving this:

// save info of last clicked Note (popup.html) in local storage as a variable //

// place variable in manifest.json under "default_popup" //

Comment: See the documentation for chrome.browserAction.setPopup

Comment: I would use chrome.storage.sync.set as it is persistent to save the variable everytime you visit page1, 2, 3.   Then run the chrome.storage.sync.get at the beginning of the script to retrieve that the stored variable and return you to that page.  Basically, have the popup.html reference a function that loads the variable and apply it to determine which popup to open.